# How does import statements work in ember-cli?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Am quite new to emberjs and ember-cli.

And I have always been wondering how a statement like this works:

```
import Ember from 'ember'
```

Does 'ember build' look up for 'ember' in node_modules?

I understand statements like this with relative paths:

```
import ENV from './config/environment'
```

but not the ones referred without a path.

This question raises in connection with [Could not find module ember-validations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175757/could-not-find-module-ember-validations), in an effort to find its root cause.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sort answer is that Ember-CLI registers the global objects directly with the module system. Take a look at the code [here](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-shims/blob/master/app-shims.js). While it's wrapped in a little helper code, they essentially do this:

```
define('ember', [], function() {
    return {
        'default': window.Ember,
    };
});
```

Then, Ember-CLI converts your `import` statement during compilation:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
```

Gets converted to:

```
var Ember = require('ember')['default'];
```

Keep in mind that this is how it's done when using a transpiler to use AMD modules. I'm not 100% sure how that code would work if we were using a native ES6 implementation, although I know that the syntax supports this kind of thing.

Comment: Great. That gives me a good insight into what the imports are transpiled into, and how the shims work.